# Cookie Configuration_Extranet_SP 2010

Tags: service-application

We are using Extranet site(SharePoint 2010).Please clarify below query

1. How cookies are set for the Classic mode authentication and Claims based authentication? (Session or Persistent)
2. If the cookies are set as persistent by default, then how can we change the persistent to session?

Thanks
P.Mohan

Comment: Please clarify whether you are speaking about all cookies, or only those used for authentication/authorization.

Comment: Not all cookies.Only for authentication/authorization cookies.Please clarify